# jPlayer video not playing on iPad

Tags: javascript, jquery, ipad, jplayer

I am using jPlayer to play videos on my website.

It is working fine on all browsers like firefox, safari, chrome, IE7-10 but not on iPad.

Whenever I click play button it starts and stops immediately.

Here is code

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var this_webmv = "";
    var this_mp4 = "";
    var this_poster = "";
    $("a[video_path]").click(function() {
        this_webmv = "http://video.shaklee.jp/BusinessTools/" + $(this).attr("video_path") + ".webm";
        this_mp4 = "http://video.shaklee.jp/BusinessTools/" + $(this).attr("video_path") + ".mp4";
        this_poster = "https://content.shaklee.jp/images/member/" + $(this).attr("video_path") + "_poster.jpg";
        var title = $(this).find("b").html();
        $("#videoTitle").html(title);
        $("#jquery_jplayer_1").jPlayer("setMedia", {
            webmv: this_webmv,
            m4v: this_mp4,
            poster: this_poster
        });
    });
    $("#jquery_jplayer_1").jPlayer({
        ready: function() {
            $(this).jPlayer("setMedia", {
                webmv: this_webmv,
                m4v: this_mp4,
                poster: this_poster
            });
        },
        play: function() { // To avoid both jPlayers playing together.
            $(this).jPlayer("pauseOthers");
        },
        swfPath: "//{{$smarty.server.HTTP_HOST}}{{$market_uri}}assets/javascripts/external",
        preload: 'metadata',
        supplied: "webmv, m4v",
        solution: "html, flash",
        size: {
            width: "570px",
            height: "340px",
            cssClass: "jp-video-360p"
        },
        cssSelectorAncestor: "#jp_container_1"
    });
  });
```

I tried the solutions that are mentioned here

[JQuery jPlayer autoplay not working on ipad how to show controls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10926122/jquery-jplayer-autoplay-not-working-on-ipad-how-to-show-controls)

Nothing worked for me.

Many thanks for any help.

Comment: share the a temp link for testing, i can't see any error on the code

Comment: I am sorry, I don't have the temp link for testing. It will be very helpful for me if you point me to an example that is working on iPad

Comment: their website works fine on ipad