# Jplayer is not working with mobile Browser (IPAD)

Tags: ipad, mobile-safari, jplayer

HI All,

I am working with Jplayer on IPAD, and I have implemented the Jplayer plugin and it is working with all browser with But with IPAD it is showing below error message.

> "Error Hint:- Check media URl is valid
>   Context:- Media URl could not be loaded"

Could anyone help me code snippet is given below. (I have tested with 2.4 also the same error is persisting there as well).

Below is the function inisiatating Jpalyer

```
startAudio: function() { 
    var _this = this;

    _this.initJPlayerHandlers();

    var solution_type = "flash, html";

    if($.browser.msie && parseInt($.browser.version, 10) > 8) {
        solution_type = "html, flash";
    }

    _this.jplayer_el.jPlayer({

        ready: function() {
            $(this).jPlayer(
                    "setMedia", {
                mp3: "/wd/mca.mp3?BID=" + MCA.singletons.self.bid
            }).jPlayer("play");
        },
         supplied: "mp3",
        swfPath: "js",
        solution: solution_type,
        preload: "none"
    });
},
```

I am using IPAD4 having IOS 7 and IPad mini with IOS7.This issue is coming up only with IPAD4.

Comment: I just recently deployed jPlayer in one of my projects as an audio player, and received reports that it doesn't work on iPads with iOS 7, while it worked fine on my iPad with iOS 6.
So this seems to be connected with some changes in iOS 7.

Answer (score 0):

Autoplay is not supported on iOS and Andriod

[JQuery jPlayer autoplay not working on ipad how to show controls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10926122/jquery-jplayer-autoplay-not-working-on-ipad-how-to-show-controls?rq=1)

http://www.jplayer.org/latest/quick-start-guide/example-audio-soundtrack/