# jwplayer audio is not autoplaying in iphone and ipad devices

Tags: php, jwplayer

I am writing below code to play audio using jwplayer

```
             <?php
                     $extension="m4a";
                     $audiopath="http://myapp.com/player.php";    
            ?>
        <div id="jquery_jplayer_1" class="media" autoplay></div>
        <div id="jp_container_1" class="player">
            <div class="controls">
                <div class="playback">
                    <a href="#" class="jp-play" tabindex="1"><i class="icon icon-play"></i></a>
                    <a href="#" class="jp-pause" tabindex="1"><i class="icon icon-pause"></i></a>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="controls jp-no-solution">
                <div class="playback">
                    <i class="icon icon-warning-sign warning"></i>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function() {
                $("#jquery_jplayer_1").jPlayer({
                    ready: function () {
                        $(this).jPlayer("setMedia", { "<?php echo $extension ?>": "<?php echo $audiopath ?>" });
                        $(this).jPlayer("play");
                    },
                    supplied: "<?php echo $extension ?>"
                });
                $("a").click(function(event) {
                    event.preventDefault();
                });
            });
        </script>
```

The audio is autoplaying in desktop, but it is not autoplaying in iphone and ipad devices.
Can any one tell me how to fix this problem

Comment: Is the issue that it doesn't autoplay, or that it doesn't play at all?  What if you test with this video? http://www.longtailvideo.com/jw/upload/bunny.mp4

Comment: it plays only when we clicks the play button, not autoplaying on page loads in ipad  and iphone

Answer (score 1):

There's no PHP in the code snippet.  But my guess is your `http://localhost/player.php` line is the culprit - `localhost` would be the iPhone/iPad, which probably isn't running a webserver.  That should be whatever the actual URL is to the `player.php` file.

Answer (score 1):

Autostart is disabled by iOS in html5  natively.

Check out our html5 report about this - http://www.jwplayer.com/html5/autoloop/

Comment: Also see these links: http://roblaplaca.com/blog/2010/04/14/ipad-and-iphone-html5-video-autoplay/, and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10926122/jquery-jplayer-autoplay-not-working-on-ipad-how-to-show-controls