# jPlayer video not playing in iOs - iPad and iPhone

Tags: javascript, ios, jplayer

My video is playing in all browsers for both PC and Mac - Chrome, Firefox, IE and Safari as well as Android tablets and phones. However, it will not play on an iPad or iPhone. I am testing on an iPad mini2 with iOS 9.2.

But when I sync the iPad with my computer and play the video in the iPad video app, it plays. So it seems to be an issue with JPlayer.

Here is the code I'm using:

```
   <script type="text/javascript">
      $(document).ready(function () {
          $("#jquery_jplayer_1").jPlayer({
              ready: function () {
                  $(this).jPlayer("setMedia", {
                      title: "POPPI-Introduction",
                      m4v: "/Video/POPPI-Introduction.m4v",
                      ogv: "/Video/POPPI-Introduction.ogv",
                      webmv: "/Video/POPPI-Introduction.webm"
                  });
              },
              cssSelectorAncestor: "#jp_container_1",
              size: {
                  width: "640px",
                  height: "360px",
                  cssClass: "jp-video-360p"
              },
              swfPath: "/Content/scripts",
              supplied: "m4v, ogv, webmv",
              useStateClassSkin: true,
              autoBlur: false,
              smoothPlayBar: true,
              keyEnabled: true,
              remainingDuration: true,
              toggleDuration: true
          });
      });
  </script>

<div id="jp_container_1" class="jp-video " role="application" aria-label="media player">
  <div class="jp-type-single">
    <div id="jquery_jplayer_1" class="jp-jplayer"></div>
    <div class="jp-gui">
      <div class="jp-video-play">
        <button class="jp-video-play-icon" role="button" tabindex="0">play</button>
      </div>
      <div class="jp-interface">
        <div class="jp-progress">
          <div class="jp-seek-bar">
            <div class="jp-play-bar"></div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="jp-current-time" role="timer" aria-label="time">&nbsp;</div>
        <div class="jp-duration" role="timer" aria-label="duration">&nbsp;</div>
        <div class="jp-details">
          <div class="jp-title" aria-label="title">&nbsp;</div>
        </div>
        <div class="jp-controls-holder">
          <div class="jp-volume-controls">
            <button class="jp-mute" role="button" tabindex="0">mute</button>
            <button class="jp-volume-max" role="button" tabindex="0">max volume</button>
            <div class="jp-volume-bar">
              <div class="jp-volume-bar-value"></div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="jp-controls">
            <button class="jp-play" role="button" tabindex="0">play</button>
            <button class="jp-stop" role="button" tabindex="0">stop</button>
          </div>
          <div class="jp-toggles">
            <button class="jp-repeat" role="button" tabindex="0">repeat</button>
            <button class="jp-full-screen" role="button" tabindex="0">full screen</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="jp-no-solution">
      <span>Update Required</span>
      To play the media you will need to either update your browser to a recent version or update your <a href="http://get.adobe.com/flashplayer/" target="_blank">Flash plugin</a>.
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Not enough reputation to comment.

Does the media actually load though? Or does it load but just not play? If it's the latter then this may be your problem. 
[JQuery jPlayer autoplay not working on ipad how to show controls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10926122/jquery-jplayer-autoplay-not-working-on-ipad-how-to-show-controls)

Answer from other thread:

> You're not going to be able to play video from $(document).ready() or from jPlayer's ready event. IOS specifically prevents it

I can't test this because I don't have an Ipad, but this may be your problem.